# MySQL count number occurrences

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this 2 tables:

```
Category:
cat_id|cat_type
   1  |    a
   2  |    b
   3  |    c
   4  |    d
```

and have

```
Meta:
met_id|met_name|user_id|met_type
   10 |  bla   |   2   |    1
   11 | blabla |   4   |    2
   12 |  foo   |   1   |    3
   13 | blafoo |   3   |    4
   14 | foofoo |   5   |    4
```

How can I return something like this ?

```
cat_type|occurences
  a   |     1
  b   |     1
  c   |     1
  d   |     2
```

met_type is a foreign key from `Category`.

Comment: It's just a simple `INNER JOIN` (or `LEFT JOIN` if you want to get the 0 counts, too). Please show what you've tried and we'll help you fix it, don't be a help vampire.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` + `COUNT` + `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT c.cat_type
     , COUNT(m.met_type) AS  occurrences 
FROM categoty c LEFT JOIN meta m ON c.cat_id = m.met_type 
GROUP BY c.cat_type
```

Comment: You may want to group by cat_type, not cat_id. The current query works on MySQL since GROUP BY is more relaxed than other RDBMS's, but as far as I know not on any other RDBMS.

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson : It is so hard sometimes to gather thoughts early in the morning. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cate.cat_type as 'cat_id', count(meta.met_type) as 'occurences'
FROM Category cate
LEFT JOIN Meta meta on(cate.cat_id = meta.met_type)
GROUP BY meta.met_type
```